# Python: How create a opencv Template Image Mapping? (reading playing hand cards)

Tags: python, image, opencv, screenshot

I am looking for an easy and smart way to read and interpret current playing hand cards on my screen (flash application).

- I make a screenshot in python and know the coordinates to "scan" my cards in my browser.
- Now I have an image like this:
  [image]
- How can I read this playing hand cards well? OCR (Tesseract) seems to be complicated.
- Rather I am looking for an Image-Mapping. To save all possible cards as image and then to match my current screen like:

  - Here is my current screenshot-part
  - Look in my "image"-mapping which card that is
  - Then to get a string like: "Ah-9d"

Comment: Yes, your idea is good, in particular if the card image you want to recognize are all the same. This approach is in the field of "content based image retrieval". It can be more robust if you use a visual feature vector. In you case, for example, let divide your image in 16x16 (mainly the right part) and compute a black/white/red histogram on rwos and columns should be enough

Comment: ya but how? I am looking for a code snippet or something like that. I need help to start this implementation. HOW do i create such a mapping?

Comment: This is a good starting point: [matchTemplate](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching)